# Javascript expand text fade-in

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm looking for some sort of fade in effect, using Javascript, Jquery, or just CSS, in which my text will start very small, and slowly enlarge itself until it reaches the final font size (over a duration of time that I specify). I tried manually changing the font size every tenth of a second, but I'm sure there's an easier way to do it than that.

Any suggestions?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/6zu4ouny/1/  Something like this? You can animate opacity, too....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would highly recommend [GreenSock JS](http://greensock.com/gsap) as an incredibly straightforward way to handle animating any HTML DOM elements.

An example of a very simple but effective line of animation code within a JavaScript tag or file would be the following:

```
TweenLite.from("#myTextElement", 1, {scaleX: 0.1, scaleY: 0.1, alpha: 0});
```

The example above will - over one second - animate #myTextElement (which can be most any element with an ID of "myTextElement") from a scale of 10% up to the existing scale CSS value, and from an alpha of 0% to the existing opacity CSS value.

By contrast, using **TweenLite.to** instead would have the opposite effect.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery-UI and CSS make it easy.  Here's a little demo that makes the text font size grow to 5x size 5000ms (5 seconds) using an easing that makes it more smooth.  I also dropped the animation rate to less than half the default (which will more than double the frame rate).

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>jQuery UI is Fun!</title>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <style>
    #element { font-size: 1.0em; }
  </style>

  <script>
  jQuery.fx.interval = 5;
  $(function() {
    $( "#element" ).animate({
          "font-size": "5.0em"
        }, 5000, "easeOutQuint" );
  });
  </script>
</head>
<body>
   <div id="element">This is my sample text.</div>
</body>
</html>
```

You can read more about the animate functionality here:
http://jqueryui.com/animate/

Comment: I tried something like this, but you don't get a very smooth animation with font-size + jQuery animate.

Comment: You can set the frame rate and the "easing" algorithm which will make the animation more smooth.  The default frame rate is 13ms, but you can set it to whatever you like like so:  'jQuery.fx.interval = 5;'  Also, read more about easings here:  http://api.jqueryui.com/easings/